# Locutus in VueJS template engine

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, vue-component

How can i implement [Locutus](https://github.com/kvz/locutus) in my VueJS application? I am using webpack.

I tried to to the following in my single file component:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ nl2br('My string here') }}</div>
</template>

<script>
var nl2br = require('locutus/php/strings/nl2br');

export default {
  // VueJS
}
</script>
```

It says that my template:

> can't render because $vm.nl2br, doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access methods from other libraries in the view, You can use those in any of vue methods and invoke that method from vue template, so you cab have something like following:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ getFromNl2br('My string here') }}</div>
</template>

<script>
var nl2br = require('locutus/php/strings/nl2br');

export default {
  methods: {
     getFromNl2br: function(str) {
        return nl2br(str)
     }
  }
}
</script>
```